# how to plot data from JSON object on .svg file using D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, d3.js

Image is appending as a background which is not clear.
Able to plot data on svg element which is created in this code.
But want to plot json data on image/.svg file with the following..
Will appreciate if any references...

```
  $(function(){
  makePlot();
    // $('#zoomReset').on('click',function(e){
    //  e.preventDefault();
    //  //$('#chart').empty();
    //  console.log("sadf");
    //  makePlot();
    // });
});

var makePlot = function() {
    d3.json("scatter-data-2010.json", function(dataset) {

    //Width and height
    var margin = {top: 80, right: 10, bottom: 60, left: 80},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var centered = undefined;

    //Create SVG element    
    tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "plan_tooltip")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("z-index", "10")
                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                .text("");


    var svg = d3.select("#vis")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

/// Set Scales and Distortions              

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d['n_workers_change']; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d['n_workers_change']; })])
                                 .range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d['earnings_change']; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d['earnings_change']; })])
                                 .range([height,0]);

    var color_scale = d3.scale.category20();

    //Add 2 more colors to category 20 because there are 22 parent industry categories
    var color_scale_range = color_scale.range();
    color_scale_range.push("#e6550d","#6baed6") 

    radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d['n_workers_y']; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d['n_workers_y']; }) ])
        .range([3, 15]);

    svg.append("defs")
       .append("pattern")
       .attr("id", "background")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .append("image")
       .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height); 

    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        //.attr("fill","none")
        .attr("fill","url(#background)")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)     
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(xScale).y(yScale).on("zoom", redraw));


// Tooltips for Dots
    set_tooltip_label = function (d) {
        var company_name;
        tooltip.html(d.category + "<br><strong>N Workers in 2010 (thousands)</strong>: " + d['n_workers_y']  + "<br><strong>Med. Wkly Earnings in 2010 ($)</strong>: " + d.earnings_y + "<br><strong> Category</strong>: " + d.parent_name );
        if (!(event === undefined)) {
            tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px")
        }
    };

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
       // Set cx, cy in the redraw function
       .attr("r", function(d) {
            return radiusScale(d['n_workers_y']);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color_scale(d.parent_id)
        })
        .on("mouseover", function () {
           return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
       }).on("mousemove", function (d) {
           set_tooltip_label(d);
       }).on("mouseout", function () {
           tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
       });


    // Define X axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(xScale)
                      .orient("bottom")
                      .ticks(5)
                      .tickSize(-height)
                      .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

    // Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(yScale)
                      .orient("left")
                      .ticks(10)
                     .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + " %"; })
                     .tickSize(-width);

       // Create X axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    // Create Y axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add Label to X Axis

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "x label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", width - width/2)
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom/2)
        .text("Percent Change in Number of Workers in Industry");


    // Add label to Y Axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("y", -margin.left + 5)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height/2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .text("Percent Change in Inflation Adjusted Median Weekly Earnings");

    // Add title 
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", " title")
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("y", -margin.top/2)
        .text("Changes in Employment and Salary by Industry, 2003 - 2010");

        // Add subtitle 
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "subtitle")
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("y", -margin.top/2 + 15)
        .text("Scroll and drag to zoom/pan, hover for details.");

        var objects = svg.append("svg")
            .attr("class", "objects")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        //Create main 0,0 axis lines:
        hAxisLine = objects.append("svg:line")
            .attr("class", "axisLine hAxisLine");
        vAxisLine = objects.append("svg:line")
            .attr("class", "axisLine vAxisLine");


    // Zoom/pan behavior:
    function redraw(duration) {
      var duration = typeof duration !== 'undefined' ? duration : 0;
      if (d3.event){
        //console.log("In the zoom function now");
        //console.log(d3.event.scale);
        //console.log(d3.event.translate);
          svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        }


        hAxisLine.transition().duration(duration)
            .attr("x1",0)
            .attr("y1",0)
            .attr("x2",width)
            .attr("y2",0)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (yScale(0)) + ")");
        vAxisLine.transition().duration(duration)
            .attr("x1",xScale(0))
            .attr("y1",yScale(height))
            .attr("x2",xScale(0))
            .attr("y2",yScale(-height));        


        circles.transition().duration(duration)
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(d['n_workers_change']);
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(d['earnings_change']);
       })

    }; // <-------- End of zoom function
  redraw(0); // call zoom to place elements
}); // end of json loading section
};
```

Comment: In SVG 1.1 `rect` elements can't have `image` children. Any such image elements are ignored when rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the background image as a pattern and then fill the `rect` with that pattern:

```
svg.append("defs")
   .append("pattern")
   .attr("id", "background")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
   .attr("fill", "url(#background)");
```

Comment: Still background image is not visible.. Do I need to add any transparency ?

Comment: Able to add image but it not at all clear. Image need to zomm and pan.

Comment: The rect element requires width and height attributes (with positive number values) to be visible. Also, the other alternative (if you don't want to fill the entire rect) is to insert the image element directly after the rect element in question, that will make it display on top of the rect.

Comment: Want to upload circles on svg file from json with zoom and pan functionality. While zooming circle should not zoom but they should translate on their zoomed position. This is my actual requirement is. With this what are the suggestions..

Comment: This is an entirely different question. Have a look at the D3 zoom behaviour.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : I am able to plot data and able to zoom and pan but this behaviour should happen on image/pdf/svg file.... Never found any useful link on Google with D3.js

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I suggest asking another question for this.